# Android gradle preBuild

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to figure out why when I'm trying to build a debug version both preDebugBuild and preReleaseBuild task are called:

From my gradle console:

```
:client:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:client:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:client:checkDebugManifest
:client:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
```

Thanks

Comment: 3 years later this comes up from google and still no answer :(